# How to upload Image in Android Studio

Tags: android, image, upload

this is my .java class

```
package com.example.gas4u;

    private void showImagePickDialog() {
        //options to display in dialog
        String[] options = {"Camera","Gallery"};
        //dialog
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle("Pick Image")
                .setItems(options, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which){
                        //handle items clicks
                        if (which == 0){
                            //camera clicked
                            if (checkCameraPermission()){
                                //permission granted
                                pickFromCamera();
                            }
                            else{
                                //permission not granted, request
                                requestCameraPermission();
                            }
                        }
                        else{
                            //gallery clicked
                            if (checkStoragePermission()){
                                //permission granted
                                pickFromGallery();
                            }
                            else{
                                //permission not granted
                                requestStoragePermission();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }).show();
    }

    // You can do the assignment inside onAttach or onCreate, i.e, before the activity is displayed
    ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> someActivityResultLauncher = registerForActivityResult(
            new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(),
            new ActivityResultCallback<ActivityResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onActivityResult(ActivityResult result ) {
                    if (result.getResultCode() == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                        // There are no request codes
                        Intent data = result.getData();

                        if (result.getResultCode() == IMAGE_PICK_GALLERY_CODE){
                            //image picked from gallery

                            //save picked image uri
                            image_uri = data.getData();

                            //set image
                            productIconIv.setImageURI(image_uri);
                        }
                        else if (result.getResultCode() == IMAGE_PICK_CAMERA_CODE){
                            //image picked from camera

                            productIconIv.setImageURI(image_uri);
                        }

                    }
                }
            });

    private void pickFromGallery(){
        //intent to pick image from gallery
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
        intent.setType("image/*");
        someActivityResultLauncher.launch(intent);
        //(intent, IMAGE_PICK_GALLERY_CODE);
    }

    private void pickFromCamera(){
        //intent to pick image from camera

        //using media store to pick high/original quality image
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE, "Temp_Image_Title");
        contentValues.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DESCRIPTION, "Temp_Image_Description");

        image_uri = getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, contentValues);

        Intent intent= new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, image_uri);
        someActivityResultLauncher.launch(intent);
        //startActivityForResult(intent, IMAGE_PICK_CAMERA_CODE);
    }

    private boolean checkStoragePermission(){
        boolean result = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) ==
                (PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
        return result; //returns true or false
    }

    private void requestStoragePermission(){
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, storagePermission, STORAGE_REQUEST_CODE);
    }

    private boolean checkCameraPermission(){
        boolean result = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) ==
                (PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);

        boolean result1 = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) ==
                (PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);

        return result && result1;
    }

    private void requestCameraPermission(){
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, cameraPermissions, CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE);
    }


    //handle permission results
    public void onRequestPermissionResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permission, @NonNull int[] grantResults){
        switch (requestCode){
            case CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE:{
                if (grantResults.length>0){
                    boolean cameraAccepted = grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
                    boolean storageAccepted = grantResults[1] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
                    if (cameraAccepted && storageAccepted){
                        //both permission granted
                        pickFromCamera();
                    }
                    else{
                        //both or one permissions denied
                        Toast.makeText(this, "Camera & Storage permissions are required...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            }
            case STORAGE_REQUEST_CODE:{
                if (grantResults.length>0){
                    boolean storageAccepted = grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
                    if (storageAccepted){
                        //permission granted
                        pickFromGallery();
                    }else{
                        //permission denied
                        Toast.makeText(this, "Storage permissions is required...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permission, grantResults);
```

I do not know how to upload an image into Android Studio, I have looked into many videos in Youtube but I am not sure if I implement it correctly, since StartActivityForResult has been fabricated I try to follow the video in the Youtube how to implement it the new way, however it is not working. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Here is the help for you : https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-select-an-image-from-gallery-in-android/                                      https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-open-camera-through-intent-and-display-captured-image-in-android/

Comment: onActivityResult cannot be used anymore to open the camera and select image. Do you have any other alternatives? @KaranMehta

Comment: You can still use startActivityForResult to open the camera. But what is wrong with your implementation?